# remove child img tag when figure is flipped

Tags: css, animation

I am currently working with transform animation.
When my mouse cursor is over the figure tag, it should be flipped and child img tag SHOULD BE HIDDEN.

```
        <section id="FollowUs" class="container">
        <figure class="col-md-4 facebook">
            <img class="img-fluid facebook" src="http://www.orchidbox.com/userfiles/facebook_homepage(1).png">
            <figcaption>Facebook</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-fluid instagram" src="https://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/How-to-embed-Instagram-videos-and-photos-on-a-website-Step-1_.jpg">
            <figcaption>Instagram</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-fluid youtube" src="https://s.aolcdn.com/hss/storage/midas/7d58b1a08ffd698700a4388ee4f3f7fa/205220657/home-before.jpg">
            <figcaption>Youtube</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure class="col-md-4">
            <img class="img-fluid google" src="https://nickhughesblog.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/jan-2012.png">
            <figcaption>Google</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </section>
```

My CSS:

```
section#FollowUs figure{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  padding:0;
  -webkit-transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
 }

 section#FollowUs img{
  border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -o-border-radius:10px;
  -ms-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  backface-visibility:hidden;
 }
 figure.facebook:hover{
  -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
 }
 figure.facebook{
  background-color:#3b5998;
 }
 figure.instagram{
   background-color:#cd486b;
 }
 figure.youtube{
  background-color:red;
 }
 figure.google{
   background-color:#000;
  }
```

With my code, flipping is working but img won't be removed.

```
$('section#FollowUs figure').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).find('img').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Tried this javascript code. It removes the image but I don't see background-color of the figure tag.

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.
I made several mistakes.
First, background-color for figcaption isn't necessary.

Second, I made duplicate selector. There were two figure.google selectors.

Third, I didn't set class of figure tags

Last, no background was shown after flipping because there wasn't any background style for figure.facebook DOM element.

Now it works fine 
This is the css code which works fine

```
section#FollowUs figure{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
padding:0;
-webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease-in-out;

}

section#FollowUs img{
border-radius:10px;
-webkit-border-radius:10px;
-o-border-radius:10px;
-ms-border-radius:10px;
-moz-border-radius:10px;
backface-visibility:hidden;
}
figure.facebook:hover, figure.google:hover, figure.instagram:hover, 
figure.youtube:hover{
-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
figure.facebook{
background-color:#3b5998;
}
figure.instagram{
background-color:#cd486b;
}
figure.youtube{
background-color:red;
}
figure.google{
background-color:#000;
}
```

javascript

```
$('section#FollowUs figure').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).find('img').css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

Comment: The code in your answer is almost identical to the code in your question (basically, you added the missing `figure.*:hover`), making it hard to see the benefit of this question-answer pair.